Rotational Motion object rotating about its axis
if an object is rotating about its internal axis then why donot we take any force as centripetal force but we consider  if it is rotating about an fixed axis outside the body then we consider centripetal force is acting.

Hi and welcome! Your question is unfortunately not very clear - would it be possible for you to rewrite it slightly?

I want to just know that if an object is rotating about its any internal axis  then why don't we consider center of mass

@MuditDagar - who says we do not consider the center of mass?

I mean centripetal force

MuditDagar Every particle in the object does experience a centripetal force. Otherwise the particle would not stick to the object and complete the rotation along with the object. When exactly do you mean that we don't consider centripetal force?

System - the object
If the axis of rotation passes through the centre of mass of the object then no external force needs to be applied for the object to continue rotating about that axis as the centre of mass of the object is not accelerating.
For all other axes the centre of mass of the object is acceleration and so must have an external (centripetal) force acting on it in order to rotate about that axis.

If the net force on the object is 0 and I consider the axis through any other point inside the body except center of mass then do I need to consider centripetal force??

If you choose another axis, inside or outside the object, then the centre of mass must be rotating about that axis (accelerating) and so must have an external force acting on it.

Okay, But if I choose an axis inside the object then centripetal force would be some internal force and it would be balanced??

The system is the object.  Internal forces within the object are paired (N3L) so that the net force due to internal forces is zero.


if an object is rotating about its internal axis then why donot we
take any force as centripetal force

We do have centripetal forces. But the centripetal forces are internal to the object.
If a rigid body is rotating at constant angular velocitey about an internal axis through its center of mass (COM) then all of the particles in that body away from the COM experience a centripetal force directed towards the COM that keeps the particles in place. The centripetal forces are the molecular bonds between the particles.
But since the centripetal force acting on any particular particle a distance $r$ from the COM is equal opposite to another centripetal force acting on another particle a distance $r$ opposite to the first particle, there is a net force of zero on the two particles. As this applies to all the particles, the sum of all the centripetal forces is zero and the body as a whole experiences no net external force and acceleration.

...but we consider if it is rotating about an fixed axis outside the
body then we consider centripetal force is acting.

In this case the centripetal force acting on the body is external to the body. An example is the Earth orbiting the Sun. The external centripetal force acting on the Earth is the force of gravity of the Sun.
Hope this helps.

Earth also rotates about its axis if I consider Only its rotation then centripetal force would be zero??

@MuditDagar I'm not sure what your point is. The Earth alone is covered by my first paragraph. The net centripetal force of all the particles of the Earth is zero, but that doesn't mean there are no centripetal forces acting on the particles of the Earth. For the Earth rotating  about the Sun example, relative to the Sun the Earth can be considered a point particle

Arguably we do consider centripetal force when an object is rotating about its axis.  However, for purposes of calculating where the center of mass of that object goes, the fact that the axis of rotation goes through the center of mass indicates that the center of mass experiences no centripetal acceleration effects ($r=0$).
If we consider any arbitrary point on the object, we do consider centripetal accelerations effets at that point.
In other words, its less that we don't consider it, and more that its effect is 0.  In many settings, we just omit these 0 effects entirely, as a convenience when speaking about the system.
